# Java wrapper class with dynamic List type

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I need to create some kind of response wrapper (in Rest controller). All mappings should return some necessary fields and some field specific to each class.

For example I have a mapping that returns list of objects of class `User` and one that returns a list of objects of type `Account`. Result is **always** of type `List` (that I'm getting from `JdbcTemplate`) because it could contain more that one User/Account:

```
public class User {

    private String name;
    private String jobTitle;

    // constructor, getters, setters
}

public class Account {

    private String id;
    private String type;

    // constructor, getters, setters
}
```

And I have a wrapper:

```
public class Wrapper {
    public String requestDate;
    public String result;
    public List<?> resultObject; // should be User or Account

    // constructor, getters, setters
}
```

How can I make it possible to create an instance of wrapper like this:

```
//suppose I have a List of User objects called myUserList;
Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper(today, "success", User.class, myUserList);
```

It looks similar to Spring's `BeanPropertyRowMapper<T>` but I stucked on implementing such for me.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: In a very crud way, you can use `public List<Object> resultObject;` and any type of object list can be assigned. But it will make it tought for the consumer of your service to deserialize the response.

Comment: Why not put requestDate and result into custom response headers? That would leave your message body to contain just the resource representation.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if i correctly understood your question but you can use generics in this way

```
public class Wrapper<T> {
    public String requestDate;
    public String result;
    public List<T> resultObject; 

    // constructor, getters, setters
}
```

As yuo can see you defined wrapper in a "generic way"; now everytime you build a wrapper instance you can specify a class; for example if you want to create a wrapper of User:

```
List<User> myUserList = new ArrayList<User>();
Wrapper<User> usrWrap = new Wrapper(today, "success", myUserList);
```

I hope it is usefull

Angelo

Answer (score 0):

What about using something like this:

***Wrapper abstract class:***

```
public abstract class Wrapper {
    public String requestDate;
    public String result;

    // constructor, getters, setters
}
```

***User Wrapper class:***

```
public class UserWrapper extends Wrapper {

    public List<User> resultObject; 

    // constructor, getters, setters
}
```

***Account Wrapper class:***

```
public class AccountWrapper extends Wrapper {

    public List<Account> resultObject; 

    // constructor, getters, setters
}
```

***Consumption:***

```
UserWrapper userWrapper = new Wrapper(today, "success", myUserList);

AccountWrapper accountWrapper = new Wrapper(today, "success", myAccountList);

List<Wrapper> wrapperList = Array.asList(userWrapper, accountWrapper);
```